# Form transparente com imagem C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image, opacity

Seguinte estou fazendo uma telinha de tutorial para o programa, não achei uma boa solução para fazer.

Criei uma tela por cima de outra com transparência, até ai tudo bem, mas quando colocava uma imagem nesta tela, ela também ficava transparente. Então criei uma terceira tela, está totalmente transparente e com as imagens, até ai tudo bem, mas as imagens ficaram pixeadas ou quadriculadas, fica bem desfocado da pra ver o pixels ao redor dela, não sei como se chama este efeito, mas enfim, não consigo deixar elas bonitas por assim dizer.

Já tentei com uma PictureBox, mas fica com o fundo preto, tentei também com o código abaixo, esse fica transparente, porem fica como descrevi pixeadas:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    RectangleF rect = new RectangleF((this.Size.Width * 0.26f) / 2, (this.Size.Height * 0.26f) / 2, this.Size.Width * 0.84f, this.Size.Height * 0.84f);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.img, rect);
}
```

Se algué tiver alguma ideia de como pode ser feito, ou se pode ser feito com menos Form's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, não sei se entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas vamos lá:
Se seu objetivo é ter um form transparente com uma imagem em cima, adicione a PictureBox normalmente e, na classe do seu Form, dentro do construtor, você cola o seguinte código:

```
this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Seu construtor ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
public MyForm() { // construtor do seu Form
    InitializeComponent(); // inicialização dos controls presentes no Form e etc
    this.BackColor = Color.Magenta; // ou qualquer outra cor muito incomum (de preferência uma que não exista na imagem)
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta; // igual à cor de fundo do Form
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // se quiser remover as bordas do Form
}
```

Alternativamente, se você estiver utilizando o Visual Studio pode acessar as propriedades no Design do seu Form e lá vai encontrar as três opções: BackColor, TransparencyKey e FormBorderStyle. Aí é só mudar elas pros valores do código acima e o VS mesmo adiciona o código pra você dentro do método `InitializeComponent();`.

EDIT: Você pode também substituir a PictureBox colocando a imagem desejada como BackgroundImage do seu Form. Apesar de que, eu já fiz antes utilizando a PictureBox e no fim tem o mesmo resultado visualmente.

Comment: Foi mais ou menos isso que utilizei, porém com a cor preta, mas será que teria como diminuir um pouco a borda do pictureBox? A borda ficou meio chamativa para a imagem que utilizo. @Vinicius